# Data binding in c# between c# components?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, data-binding

Can we bind the listofradiobuttons with listofstring in c#? Can we perform data binding between .net components like radiobuttons or richtextboxes because mostly I found data binding tutorial on data binding between components and data base.

Answer (score 1):

yeah Ofcourse you can bind

```
Class MyAccount
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}

List<MyAccount> li=new List<MyAccount>();
MyAccount m1=new MyAccount{
Id=1,
Name='abc'
};
MyAccount m2=new MyAccount{
Id=2,
Name='def'
};
li.add(m1);
li.add(m2);

DropDown.DataSource=li;
DropDown.DataTextField="Name";
DropDown.DataValueField="Id";
DropDown.DataBind();
```

First made a class with two prop. Then make list of that. add items in list. Assign list's datasource property to any collection (like dictionary, hastable etc) or dataset.
Assign it's data text and data value field property and dont forget to bind it by calling DataBinde() function. That's All.

Comment: but im asking how can i bind string against radiobutton